# How I can hide chromedriver log on console through selenium p

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, windows-10, selenium-chromedriver

How do I hide console window?

I using headless chrome and selenium in gui app to scraping data from one web page.
When starting the app, open console window then display log of chromedriver.

Is there a way to hide chromedriver log on console when starting the app?

OS: windows10
python: 3.6.3
selenium 3.8.0
chromedriver: 2.33
Google Chrome canary

Comment: Your code trial please?

Comment: Please provide an example. I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\services.py** file

In **Service** class

in func **start** add creationflags argument

```
try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                       close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows', 
                                       stdout=self.log_file, 
                                       stderr=self.log_file,
                                       creationflags=0x08000000,
                                       stdin=PIPE)
except TypeError: ...
```